# Real Variable Theory

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

Question 5 (a) is puzzling me, since I know the prove for when f(x)=l and g(x)=m, where m and l are limits so f(x)+g(x)=l+m. But, to answer it where they both tend to infinity would i need to use the dentition of a function tending to infinity? And how would i use the definition in order to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Given a number $L$ you need to find $x_0$ such that, if $x>x_0$ then $(f+g)(x) > L$ and you alredy know there are numbers $x_1, x_2$ such that, if $x>x_1$ $f(x) > L$ and if $x>x_2$ then $g(x) > L$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint: Definition of Infinite Limit**
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=\infty $$
If for every number $N\gt 0$, there exists some number $M\gt 0$ such that $f(x)\gt N$ whenever $x\gt M$.

Comment: a in this case would be infinity

Comment: My lecture gave me this definition : Given any A>0 there exists a real number K which may depend on A such that f(x)>A when x>K, how would i create one for g(x)?